# How to use Tensorflow to compute per-sample gradient and reduce them with an arbitrary function?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

Given a (mini-)batch of size M, I want to acquire M gradients (one for each sample) and reduce them to a single gradient with an arbitrary function (instead of the typical mean). Then, I want to use this last gradient to train the network with.

I have the example below which somewhat works. The problem is that not only it gets slower and slower as iterations go by, but also the programs keeps on using more and more memory. As far as I can tell, this happens because I'm adding new operations to Tensorflow's computational graph on each iteration, but I lack the knowledge of Tensorflow to avoid doing this and still achieve my objective.

```
import sys

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# Import MNIST data
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot=True)


# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.0001
n_iterations = 1000000
batch_size = 2
display_step = 1000

# Network Parameters
n_hidden_1 = 256
n_hidden_2 = 256
n_input = 784
n_output = 10


# Create model
def build_network(x, weights, biases):
    assert sys.version_info[:2] >= (3,6)  # otherwise iteration on dict is ill-defined

    layer = x

    for (w_str,w),(b_str,b) in zip(weights.items(), biases.items()):
        print(w_str,b_str)

        layer = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer, w), b)

    return layer


def max_gradient(gradients):
    assert len(gradients) >= 1

    # compute the resulting gradient, by choosing the (abs) max component wise
    tgv = gradients[0]

    for gv in gradients[1:]:
        for (tg,tv),(g,v) in zip(tgv,gv):
            assert (tv == v).all()

            np.copyto(tg,g,where=abs(g) > abs(tg))

    return tgv


def main(sess):
    # tf Graph input/output
    X = tf.placeholder('float', [None, n_input])
    Y = tf.placeholder('float', [None, n_output])

    # Store layers weight & bias
    weights = {
        'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden_1])),
        'h2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2])),
        'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2, n_output]))
    }
    biases = {
        'b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1])),
        'b2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2])),
        'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_output]))
    }

    # Construct model
    model = build_network(X, weights, biases)

    # Loss
    loss_op = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=model, labels=Y))

    # Optimizer
    opt = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)

    # Gradient
    gv_op = opt.compute_gradients(loss_op)

    # Trainable variables
    t_vars = tf.trainable_variables()

    # Initializing the variables
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    # Training cycle
    for i in range(n_iterations):
        # Get new training data
        X_train, Y_train = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)

        # Run the cost operation (to get the loss value)
        c = sess.run(loss_op, feed_dict={X: X_train, Y: Y_train})

        print(i, c)

        # get the gradients for each batch sample
        gradients = [sess.run(gv_op,
                              feed_dict={X: X_train[[j]], Y: Y_train[[j]]})
                     for j in range(batch_size)]

        # compute the resulting gradient
        tgv = max_gradient(gradients)

        # assert that all the variables match
        for (_,v1),v2 in zip(tgv,t_vars):
            assert (v1 == sess.run(v2)).all()

        # place the actual variables for the variable slots
        tgv = [(g,v) for (g,_),v in zip(tgv, t_vars)]

        # apply the transformation
        sess.run(opt.apply_gradients(tgv))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        main(sess)
```

How can I compute per-sample gradient and reduce them with an arbitrary function without constantly adding new operations to Tensorflow's graph?